# Maven Compile Plugin By Command

Tags: java, maven

I have a project in Windows-1254 file encoding and some of files are in UTF-8 encoding.

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Windows-1254</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>Windows-1254</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <version.plugin.maven.resources>3.1.0</version.plugin.maven.resources>
        <functionAppName>az-app-core</functionAppName>
    </properties>
```

I added plugin in pom and compiles correctly with `mvn compile`.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/StringUtil.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/TurkceInputTag_FaceLift.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/TurkceInputTag.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <encoding>Windows-1254</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                             <include>**/StringUtil.java</include>
                            <include>**/TurkceInputTag_FaceLift.java</include>
                            <include>**/TurkceInputTag.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

But I need to compile project by command not just `clean compile` but also give all configurations(defined above compile1, compile2 executions) to maven like

maven *compile-plugin*:compile -Dexecutions/execution1/id=compile1,encoding=Windows-1254,excludes=....

I can't change File types encoding to only UTF-8 or Windows-1254 encoding. I need to compile project using both 2 encoding.

How can maven plugin compiles by command with configurations, encoding,executions etc.?

Comment: Make a single encoding for all source files otherwise it does not make sense ...and your configuration is going the wrong way furthermore how would you like to do unit testing etc. ?

Comment: Could you please explain, _why_ you see a problem in converting all the source code files to UTF-8? It would be really important that you give a detailed explanation on the reasons that stop you from doing this.

Comment: It would be great if you add some explanation to your question.

Comment: Question is clear I think,
How maven compiling by command with full configuration is done with given sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the command line for Maven is not as flexible as you might like it to be for what you're wanting to achieve. (I have quite a big question about *why* you're trying to achieve it, and can't just specify that information in the POM as you've demonstrated).

If you look at the [goal documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) for `maven-compiler-plugin:compile`, you'll see that some of the options, like [`encoding`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding), have a 'user property'. This, prefixed with `-D` to make it a system property, allow you to configure it from the command line:

```
mvn <goals/phases> -Dencoding=... -Dmaven.compiler.failOnError=...
```

But running a goal from the command line will give a single execution, not the set of two that you want. So your options might be:

- Run the `mvn` command twice, with different options on each one. Tricky though as you can't specify inclusions/exclusions.
- Split the project into more than one, having different options for encoding in each, and run those from the command line.
- Get around whatever limitation it is that is giving you this issue in the first place, and run from the POM as you've defined rather than on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I second khmarbaise.

All source code files in one project need to have *the same* encoding. Choose one and convert the other source code files.

EDIT:

You mentioned that you could not convert the files, but unfortunately, you did not tell us why.

Whatever hinders you to do it, you need to solve that issue.

So if your colleagues, managers or customers tell you *not* to change encoding, then you need to solve this problem by talking to these people, explaining them that a Maven project needs to have one (and just one) source code encoding and convincing them to change that.

Feel free to comment on my answer if I misunderstood you.

Comment: It's not really a Maven requirement it's a general requirement to have a consistent encoding within your projects. That makes working easier for all people.